# The Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem in Coefficient Ring $G$

Tags: algebraic-topology

As you know Lefschetz number is $\tau (f)\doteq \sum_n (-1)^n 
{\rm tr}(f_\ast : H_n(X)\rightarrow H_n(X))$ where $X$ is a finite simplicial complex and $f : X\rightarrow X$. So 
LFPT is that if $\tau(f)\neq \emptyset$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Here I want to know whether or not LFPT holds 
if the coefficient ring $G$ is ${\bf Z}_p$. Thank in advance.

Comment: Does the proof that involves replacing $f$ up to homotopy by a simplicial map $g$ that "moves all the cells" not go through?